# reg expression for a number

Tags: regex

I want a regular expression for a number which is a continuous string of digits with no spaces - Please help !
Thankyou

Comment: can you post some example string to match?

Comment: for instance, "some45b40" , is there match or 45 and 40 matches?

Answer (score 5):

This is the simplest:

```
^\d+$
```

This regular expression matches only sequences of one or more digits. `^` and `$` mark the start and end of the string respectively.

But this would also allow numbers with leading zeros. If you don’t want that, use this:

```
^(0|[1-9]\d*)$
```

This matches either a single `0` or a number beginning with `1`..`9` followed by zero or more arbitrary digits.

Comment: `^` and `$` mark the beginning and end of line respectively - this won't match `a123456b` because of the non-digit characters. It's not clear to me that that's what the OP was after.

Comment: Then again, it's not clear that it's *not* what the OP wants either.

Answer (score 2):

If it is just for regex:

**\d**
    Matches any decimal digit; this is equivalent to the class [0-9].

So you can write

**\d* or [0-9]*** - from empty string to continuous string of digits

**\d+ or [0-9]+** - at least one digit

If you want to know how to use this in specific language, specify the language pls.

Answer (score 1):

`\d+` will work in most implementations.

`\d` indicates `digit` - if your implemenation doesn't have this, use `[0-9]+` instead.

`+` means `one or more of the preceeding pattern`.

edit: Here's an example in python illustrating the difference between `+` and `*`:

```
>>> import re
>>> r = re.compile('[0-9]*')
>>> print r.findall('asdf')
['', '', '', '', '']
>>> r = re.compile('[0-9]+')
>>> print r.findall('asdf')
[]
>>> print r.findall('abc12345ghi')
['12345']
>>> r = re.compile('^[0-9]+$')
>>> print r.findall('abc12345ghi')
[]
```

Answer (score -1):

d*
or
[0-9]*
depending on implementation I guess...

Comment: You meant `\d`, right? Use `+` instead of `*` : `\d*` will match even and empty string.

Comment: `*` means `0 or more`, so this would match `[0-9]*` would match an empty string. Worse, given the string `abcd` this would return 5 matches: one at the start and end of the string, and one between each character. Each match would be 0-length. `+` stipulates `1 or more` and wouldn't do this.